# Filter out App Center analytics by IP address

Tags: azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

We are currently using **Microsoft App Center Analytics** for our Xamarin Forms app (IOS and Android). We will be pulling the analytics data through Azure Application Insights as well.

We would like to remove or filter out the analytics events from out Test and Development devices. Are there any recommended approaches for doing this? Is there something built into App Center that we should be taking advantage of?

We could do something simple and blunt that just swallow calls to `Analytics.TrackEvent` when it is a DEBUG build but that doesn't cover Test devices that would be running in release mode.

Comment: Not familiar with App center, but it would be easy to do this in the application insights to filter these messages.

Comment: How do you do it in Application Insights? Is the data still there but you simply filter it out by IP address in a custom query?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do in application insights. But if you prefer do it in app center, I have no idea:(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm late for the party. My problem was to ignore the local traffic (dev testers and QA testers) and capture only the external usage (customers) of the app.

My solution was to give two different builds, one for QA and another for production.

Step 1:
Register 2 apps on the [app center](https://appcenter.ms/) and obtain 2 app secrets

Step 2:
Create two build configurations in VS 2022. I have created "Internal_QA_Release" and "Release" configurations.
[image]

Step 3:
Do a code change to switch the app center initialization via C# "preprocessor directives".

```
    #if INTERNAL_QA_RELEASE
                AppCenter.Start("a8218b7ae74f5a9",
                           typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
    #endif

    #if RELEASE
                    AppCenter.Start("94646a-3f7c1bc2b88f",
                       typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
    #endif
```

Step 4:
Finally do the internal releases by switching to "Internal_QA_Release" solution configuration and for production use the "Release" solution configuration.

Comment: This is exactly what we ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom event with property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin#custom-events.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When you are answering with a link please provide an explanation with that, so if the link gets broken in the future, others can still understand the answer.